# How to extract date and time from filename in python?

Tags: python, string, date, extract

I want to extract the date and time written on the filename. I want the date and time to be in two seperate columns called date and time.
How should I write my script to get the correct date and from the filename.
Thanks in advance.

I have written a script but it is giving an error. The script is:

```py
from datetime import datetime
file_name = "CCN-200 data 200605202252.csv"
date_time = str(re.split("\s", file_name, 2))
date_time  = datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

**ValueError:** time data "\['CCN-200', 'data', '200605202252.csv'\]" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'
```

the expected output is:

```
df\[date\] = 2020-06-05,
df\[time\] = 20:22:52
```

Comment: You get a Value error, which means there is something wrong with one of the values in your code. The error message points out that you are trying to parse the string `"\['CCN-200', 'data', '200605202252.csv'\]` against the pattern `"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"`. It seem `str(re.split("\s", file_name, 2))` is not producing the output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re.split("\s", file_name, 2)
```

will return an array like: `['CCN-200', 'data', '200605202252.csv']` casting it to a string will not solve your initial problem as you need to get the last element from the arrray, strip the file ending and **then** do your datetime logic.

If you can be sure that your files always have this format i would recommend to build a regex that searches 12 digits and use this match for further date transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the datetime module just with some careful string splitting and create your dataframe (which seems to be a requirement) from a dictionary as follows:

```
import pandas

file_name = 'CCN-200 data 200605202252.csv'

*_, ds = file_name.split()

date = f'20{ds[:2]}-{ds[2:4]}-{ds[4:6]}'
time = f'{ds[6:8]}:{ds[8:10]}:{ds[10:]}'

print(pandas.DataFrame({'date':[date],'time':[time]}))
```

**Output:**

```
         date      time
0  2020-06-05  20:22:52
```

**Note:**

The filename format must be similar to the example in the question. In particular the date/time part must be a 12-digit sequence at the start of the last whitespace delimited token in the filename

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filename always follow the same pattern (ig word word datetime.csv)

```
import pandas as pd

    file_name = "CCN-200 data 200605202252.csv"

    date_str = file_name.split()[2][:6] // 200605
    time_str = file_name.split()[2][6:12] // 202252

    datetime_obj = pd.to_datetime(date_str + time_str, format="%y%m%d%H%M%S")

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "time"])
    df.loc[0] = [datetime_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), datetime_obj.strftime("%H:%M:%S")]
    print(df) // shows          date      time
                             0  2020-06-05  20:22:52
```

Since you called your object "df" I'm assuming you wanna store it in a dataframe, if it's not the case you can totally store it in a simple dictionnary also

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

file_name = "CCN-200 data 200605202252.csv"

# get the date/time from the file_name (you don't necessarily need to use re)
ds = file_name.split(".")[0].split()[-1]  # split on "." first and then on whitespace

# convert to a datetime object (note: don't use the hyphens as the string has none)
date = datetime.strptime(ds, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# get calendar date in your required format
caldate = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# get time in your required format
time = date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

You can then add these to your dataframe as required

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

df["date"] = caldate
df["time"] = time
```